# Есть ли разница от перемены мест слов для поисковой оптимизации?

Tags: seo

Например, для запроса: "красный забор", "забор красный". Для URL: "krasnyi_zabor" или "zabor_krasnyi". Есть ли разница для яндекс и google? Интересует только 2, 3 слова в предложении.

Comment: @AK для поисковика

Comment: Извините, это и так было ясно по метке. Какого конкретно? Любого? Для любого поисковика подойдёт любой ответ.

Comment: @AK яндекс и google